# Apache redirect Absolue url to relative url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

So I want to load a web-app from a subfolder. Current configuration looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName YOUR IP ADDRESS/DOMAIN

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    <Directory /var/www/html/monica/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        # Everything under this line has been added by me to try to make the redirect work
        RewriteEngine  on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$           /var/www/html/monica/public/$1  [R]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The pages are being served correctly, but since the files contain absolute url, it keeps on failing. I'm really new to Apache so I don't know what I'm doing wrong and searching for answer has been futile.

If I make the DocumentRoot `/var/www/html/monica/public/` it works correctly but I want to access it from a subdirectory, something like `localhost/monica/`

A note: This webapp was made to be be accessed from the base ( https://github.com/monicahq/monica/)

Comment: "The pages are being served correctly" - Can you give an example URL? Are you directly serving physical files from the filesystem? It's just that I'm looking at your `RewriteRule` directive - there's no way that can work - you can't reference an absolute filesystem path in a _directory_ context (so I guess that isn't doing anything or you've not restarted your webserver?). "but since the files contain absolute url, it keeps on failing" - "files" as in HTML files? An absolute URL is normally a good thing so I'm not sure why that is a problem - can you include an example?

Comment: "If I make the DocumentRoot `/var/www/html/monica/public/`" - from the information given, I can't see why that would make a difference?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, I'm serving physical files.The index.php file is in the `/public/` path which references absolute path for assets like image, js, css etc and those absolute paths are based on the assumption that the root folder is `/var/www/html/monica/public/`. I can't show you a live example since the project is hosted locally, but this is the file structure https://github.com/monicahq/monica/tree/master/public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I think* I understand what you are referring to now (although an example "absolute path" of how you are referencing your assets would be useful). I assume you are referencing your assets something like `/img/image.jpg` (or `https://example.com/img/image.jpg`)? Whereas the actual resource is located at `/monica/public/img/image.jpg`? So, you basically need to rewrite all your URLs (for static assets) to the `/monica/public` subdirectory. But doesn't this also affect your inter-page URLs? (Unless you are using solely *relative* URLs between pages?)

For example, instead of your existing `<Directory>` block, try the following. Note the `Directory` path references your document root.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.+\.(?:jpg|png|css|js))$ /monica/public/$1  [L]
</Directory>
```

The purpose of the check for file extensions (of your static assets) is to avoid the "file exists" check on *every* request (which is relatively *expensive*).

This assumes that you have a `.htaccess` file located at `/monica/public/.htaccess` (as shown in your file structure) that then routes the request. (Otherwise this could result in a rewrite loop if the asset really doesn't exist.)

> If I make the DocumentRoot `/var/www/html/monica/public/` it works correctly but I want to access it from a subdirectory, something like `localhost/monica/`

However, this sounds like you should "fix" your URL-paths (routing within Laravel) instead of rewriting your resources?

---

**UPDATE:**

> can you tell me how would I do that?

I'm not sure, this would seem to be a Laravel/PHP issue? The document root would be `/var/www/html/monica/public/` (filesystem path), but you want to effectively serve your content from a `/monica` subdirectory in the *URL-path*. Note that "monica" in `/var/www/html/monica/public/` is a different "monica" to the one in your URL. You could have your webapp in a `/monica` subdirectory on the filesystem (so the absolute filesystem path would be `/var/www/html/monica/public/monica`) OR you change all the URLs in your webapp  to include `/monica/` at the start of the URL-path.

Regardless of how you do it, all the URLs in your webapp (for static resources and everything) need to start `/monica`. So, I don't see any way other than modifying your routing within Laravel.

Apache can help with *moving* content from say the document root to the `/monica` subdirectory by issuing an external redirect. But this is only for SEO benefit, not to be used all the time by your users (slower, extra load on server, etc.).

> If I change it to this ... the assets stop loading again. Do you have any idea why?
>
> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/monica>
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>     AllowOverride All
>     Require all granted
>
>     RewriteEngine  on
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule (.+\.(?:jpg|png|css|js))$ /public/$1  [L]
> </Directory>
> ```

Because (if my assumption at the start of my answer is still correct) you are referencing your assets like `/img/image.jpg` and not `/monica/img/image.jpg`.

Comment: This works; I swear I tried this exact same thing. I'm kind of new to this, so can you tell me how would I do that?

Comment: If I change it to this https://pastebin.com/fkni1Sxm the assets stop loading again. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I've updated my answer.